# Difficulty in configuring the database for domain connection repository during server installation

Tags: informatica

[the error i m getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpbsZ.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwt8v.png)My intention is to have ORACLE 12 + Informatica on my local system.
I have installed Oracle and it is working fine. While I am trying to run SERVER INSTALLATION for INFORMATICA, I am having difficulty with configuring the database for domain connection repository. The connection is failing even though I am giving correct oracle credentials which are as below:
DB USERID: **infadmin**
   JDBC URL:**localhost:1521**
   Service: **orcl**
My questions is:
Why is it failing? Do I have to do anything special before trying this connection like installing any special jdbc drivers or something?

Your replies are much awaited.Thanks in advance.

Vaibhav Gautam

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: CONNECTION FAILED. CORRECT THE CONNECTION INFORMATION AND TEST AGAIN.

Comment: Hi I'm having the same error when installing informatica. Were you able to solve it back then?

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of the tnsnames.ora file located at `<Oracle Installation Direcotry>/network/admin`. Make sure that the hostname, port no., service name matches exactly.

Also, make sure the oracle service is running.

Comment: Yes, they are identical and also,I have opened SQL PLUS at the same time and it is running fine.

Comment: but still INFORMATICA is not able to connect to db while trying to make database for DOMAIN REPOSITORY.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the details you are entering in the domain setup

Comment: Hello Samik... screenshot added. Pls take a look.

Comment: well, everything looks correct! not sure where the issue is.I hope you have created the user infadmin, and granted required privileges. Are you able to connect to the database from SQL Plus with this user id?

Comment: Yes Samik...I am able to connect on SQL PLUS. Also gave dba previleges to this userid.  Could you please send me some alternate link for informatica download? This one, I got from oracle and there 16 files instead of normal 4 in the setup that i got from edlivery.oracle.com.

Comment: I had downloaded from oracle only. Maybe they have changed the files now.